# Search for replacement character (no TSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to find a way to search for the replacement character `/uFFFD` with SQL (since I'm using MariaDB) but I can not make it work. I tried with:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE content LIKE "%\ufffd%";
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE content LIKE "%�%"
```

Both results are not working for me. Some topics say to use `UNICODE()` but it's a TSQL function and I can not use it here in MariaDB. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `CHARACTER SET` are you using?  `FFFD` is the hex for the Unicode "codepoint".  The `UTF-8` encoding for it is `EFBFBD`.

Here's another way to look for it:

```
WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '^(....)*FFFD'
```

or perhaps

```
WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '^(..)*EFBFBD'
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your results? Do you have any error? Try this simple working query or change your col type.

```
select '�' a from dual where a like '%�%'
```